# Sharepoint Online using PNP library, I shared a file with an user from AD (Object), the problem is that i can't unshare it

Tags: typescript, sharepoint, spfx

the code sends me back an error: that the function doesn't exist

```js
sp.web.unshareObject("https://cloudlabgr.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/Shared%20Documents/33-3/test.txt").then((result: SharingResult) => { 

 console.log(result);

}).catch(e => {

   console.error(e);
  });`
```

Answer (score 0):

sp.web.unshareObject has same error in my side, I used sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/dev/Shared Documents/test").unshare() as a alternative, it works:

```
  public render(): void {
    sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/dev/Shared Documents/Capture1.png").unshare().then((result: SharingResult) => {

      console.log(result);
  }).catch(e => {
      console.error(e);
  });
  }
```

[image]

Reference:

[@pnp/sp/sharing](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/docs/sharing/)